# Цикл по колонкам датафрейма

Tags: pandas

Есть датафрейм, хочу посчитать интеграл от каждого столбца, пятаюсь сделать в цикле, никак не получается.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import simps
from numpy import trapz
LT = []
x = np.arange(len(p))

for column in p.columns:
    print(column)
    y = p[column].fillna(0)
   # y = p['{}'.format(column)].fillna(0)
    print(y)
    lt = trapz(y,x, dx=1/4)/100*7
    LT.append(lt)
    

    
   
LT
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите, что у вас в `p`, а то так можно только гадать

Comment: Да и в целом уточните - что значит "не получается"?

Comment: Я попробовал с таким p - с виду всё работает  `p = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,(10,20)))`

Comment: у меня ошибка в данных - разбераюсь сейчас